# List Facet using the index field is Empty

Tags: sxa, solr, search-facet

We are trying to create a ListFacet (dropdown filter) using the Computed Index field. These are the checklist that we have in place

1. The Computed field contains values in the index file.
2. Created a List facet item and specified the Computed field as the Field Name
3. Mapped the List facet item to the Dropdown filter under Data folder
4. Added the Dropdown filter rendering on to the page and associated the datasource to \Data\Search\Dropdown Filter\Dropdown Filter

When the page was loaded, the dropdown is empty. Are there any additional steps that needs to be done to get this working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just checked and it is working fine. Take a look below:

[image]

[image]

Next, add Dropdown Filter and Search Results on the page and you should see values in the dropdown:

[image]

Keep in mind that filters won't work if there won't be Search Results on the page. They have no sense without Search Results rendering.

Comment: This worked. It was of great help. Thank you @dawid

Comment: Hello, I am new to sitecore. I am trying to build a dropdown with static items list. I really do not know what to do with ListFacet  so that the dropdown can have the list. Anyone can help? Thanks!